# python-constraint add constraint

Tags: python, constraint-satisfaction

I'm developing a python program to solve constraint satisfaction problem(CSP).

Here I have variables list **['MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303']** and their possible assignments **['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1']**.

My constraint for this is, having compatibility list for each element in 2nd list (possible assignments). It works as follows;

From the elements of first list(variables list) there is another index to get another key. From that key, I can access set of compatible values(possible assignment) in the list. To better understand consider this example:

> For variable **'MI428'** I have the key **'B320'** **('MI428->'B320')**, Then I have List of compatible values for **B320** as **['A1', 'A2']**

Here my task is to assign compatible value from **['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1']** to each of variables such as **'MI428'**, satisfying the above explained constraint.

Note: for this I'm using [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) Library. I need implementation using that. So far I created a problem instant as follows, so what I really want is adding constraint for that problem.

```
from constraint import Problem
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(['MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303'], ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1'])
problem.addConstraint() // I need this line to be implemented
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
```

I need a proper constraint for addConstraint line..

Comment: Please add some code, your reasoning behind chosing this lib and a more precise description including some example. As described you can just pick any entry for every var as there are no constraints of arity bigger 1 described. The lib also looks very very minimal/lacking.

Comment: @sascha I added code I have been trying so far, sorry for the mistake..

Comment: Thats not really a csp. Any pick for each var is a solution and the cartesian product of those allowed values define all solutions.

Comment: @sascha but the way I have modeled that uses constraint(compatible values), however that's why I think as it is.. Also I have such more constraints to add for this, for the convenience I asked one one initially..

Comment: Without context it does not make much sense to build a constraint. Just use the variable-domain for that (if that's a bad decision depends on the remainding problem): `domain - Set of items defining the possible values that the given variable may assume`.

Comment: @sascha I'm developing a bay reservation algorithm for an airport, here 'MI428'.. are flights and they have attribute air plane type, in that way a given flight with airplane type can be assigned to only compatible bays referred as compatible set in the question. Basically I need to assign a bay to a given flight..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to the constraint library, I'd strongly recommend using an SMT solver; which can scale to many planes/flights/bays with relative ease for this kind of problem. In addition, they can be scripted from many high-level languages, including Python. I'd recommend using Microsoft's Z3 for this particular problem; you can get a free copy from: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

While you can model your problem in a variety of ways, I think the following would be the idiomatic way of coding it using Z3's Python bindings:

```
from z3 import *

# Flights
Flight, (MI428, UL867, QR664, TK730, UL303) = EnumSort('Flight', ('MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303'))
flights = [MI428, UL867, QR664, TK730, UL303]

# Planes
Plane, (B320, B777, B235) = EnumSort('Plane', ('B320', 'B777', 'B235'))

# Bays
Bay, (A1, A2, B1, B2, C1) = EnumSort('Bay', ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1'))
bays = [A1, A2, B1, B2, C1]

# Get a solver
s = Solver()

# Mapping flights to planes
plane = Function('plane', Flight, Plane)
s.add(plane(MI428) == B320)
s.add(plane(UL867) == B320)
s.add(plane(QR664) == B777)
s.add(plane(TK730) == B235)
s.add(plane(UL303) == B235)

# Bay constraints. Here're we're assuming a B320 can only land in A1 or A2,
# A B777 can only land on C1, and a B235 can land anywhere.
compatible = Function('compatible', Plane, Bay, BoolSort())

def mkCompat(p, bs):
    s.add(And([(compatible(p, b) if b in bs else Not(compatible(p, b))) for b in bays]))

mkCompat(B320, [A1, A2])
mkCompat(B777, [C1])
mkCompat(B235, bays)

# Allocation function
allocate = Function('allocate', Flight, Bay)
s.add(And([compatible(plane(f), allocate(f)) for f in flights]))
s.add(Distinct([allocate(f) for f in flights]))

# Get a model:
if s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()
   print [(f, m.eval(allocate(f))) for f in flights]
else:
   print "Cannot find a satisfying assignment"
```

When I run this on my computer, I get:

```
$ python a.py
[(MI428, A1), (UL867, A2), (QR664, C1), (TK730, B2), (UL303, B1)]
```

This takes almost no time to compute, and I do trust it would scale to thousands of flights/planes/bays with no problem. Z3 being an SMT solver, you can even code arithmetic constraints such as arrival/departure times etc. in a programmatic and simple way.

Comment: I have to add some other constraints like "availability times" as well, so can I use this for that case also?? (Basically I'm having five constraints including above)

Comment: Sure. An SMT solver can be used as a general-purpose constraint solver. Note that you'll not have the same performance as you would have in a dedicated algorithm, but since SMT solvers cover many different theories (arithmetic, datatypes, booleans, reals..) most such problems can be coded easily and solved rather efficiently.

Comment: I have arrival time and departure time for each flight, can you tell me how to add that constraint as well, so that I will not get conflict when assigning bays.. note that in this case there can be same bay assigned for two flights, because of available time of bays..

Comment: I'd treat the arrival/departure time just like the plane type; no conflicts are allowed there. Should be along the lines of a function that maps each flight to a time, and requiring distinct assignment. If you try something and let us know what you get, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I have time constraints like `time_constraints = {'MI428':(1,3) , 'UL867':(4,7), 'QR664':(5,9), 'TK730':(15,19), 'UL303':(16,17)}`, can you please show me how to include this into above code, note that first element of the tuple is arrival time and the second element is departure time.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good medium for such general questions. I'd recommend looking over the Z3py tutorials, trying it out, and asking very specific questions as you have them. You can start here: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm